# Cakephp IN condition bypass duplicate ID's to fetch data

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i am using this code snippet for apply **condition** to fetch data from database

```
array( 'Account.type_id' => $account_type_id_ids );
```

where **$account_ids for example is {3,10}**.
i am passing through

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 10
)
```

but in accounts table there is multiple rows with these ID's

like :

```
id    | type_id
1     |    2
2     |    3
3     |    2
4     |    3
5     |    10
```

so this must be fetch rows {2,4,5}
but when i print_r this data i got a list of only {2,5}
i want to fetch all those three

Comment: What is the SQL query being generated by Cake for your find?

Comment: please share your cakephp query code

Comment: it is very big , but i can show a snippet that you want.
WHERE `Account`.`type_id` IN (3, 10)

Comment: To me this sounds as if you are using some kind of grouping.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please try this one if you are using cakephp 2.6

```
array( 'Account.type_id IN' => "'.$account_type_id_ids.'" );
```

Comment: In Cake you should really be using an array for the values of the `IN` query like `array( 'Account.type_id IN' => [3, 10]);` rather than attempting to build the condition yourself.

Comment: -1 How can this be a solution anyways? This will yield an "array to string conversion" notice, and end up as invalid SQL like `Account.type_id IN '\'.Array.\''`.